# ActiveShipping and Grape (Rails) - uninitialized constant API::V1::Shippings::ActiveShipping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api, uninitialized-constant

I use [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) to create an API in rails. Now I want to use Shopify's [Active Shipping gem](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) but when I try to use this in my custom_helper within Grape I get a `uninitialized constant ActiveShipping` error message. In addition I also get the following message:

`Cannot render console with content type application/jsonAllowed content types: [#<Mime::Type:0x007f8bea21b4e8 @synonyms=["application/xhtml+xml"], @symbol=:html, @string="text/html">, #<Mime::Type:0x007f8bea21b038 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:text, @string="text/plain">, #<Mime::Type:0x007f8bec0fe950 @synonyms=[], @symbol=:url_encoded_form, @string="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">]`

my helper file looks like:

```
require 'active_shipping'
module API
    module V1
        module Helpers
            module ShippingHelpers
                extend Grape::API::Helpers

                def ups_tracking_info(tracking_number)
                    ups = ActiveShipping::UPS.new(login, password, key) #this is where it throws an error
                    ups.find_tracking_info(tracking_number)
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and I include it in my grape shippings file like:

```
module API
  module V1
    class Shippings < Grape::API
        helpers API::V1::Helpers::ShippingHelpers 
       ...
        #some endpoint:
          ups_tracking_info(tracking_info)
       ...
    end
  end
end
```

Why do I get the uninitialized constant error message? I do require the gem in my helper file.. requireing it in my config/application.rb file doesn't work either...

Hope someone will have an idea, that can help me further. Thanks in Advance!

Note I have all my grape files in app/api/api folder so that is not the problem..

Comment: Try `::ActiveShipping::UPS` so that it looks for the class at the root level, not within `API::V1::Shippings`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Philip. Unfortunately it didn't help.. Please see my answer below. It turned out the documentation was incorrect and I needed to use ``include ActiveMerchant::Shipping`` in my class.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the [documentation with the gem on github](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) is incorrect. The correct information is written [here](http://shopify.github.io/active_shipping/). I had to `include ActiveMerchant::Shipping` in my class and drop the use of ActiveMerchant::Shipping within the code. So use UPS.new() or FedEx.new() etc. instead.

Comment: You could also probably not do that and just do  `::ActiveMerchant::Shipping::UPS....`

Comment: I guess, thanks for the suggestion! Still documentation with gem wasn't correct...